# Splunk Query - group events by fields in splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

I have some log events in Splunk which appears something like following:

```
Payment request to app_name_foo for brand: B1, app_id: A1, some param: blah, another param: blahblahblah, payment method: CREDITCARD, last param: someuniquestring

Payment request to app_name_foo for brand: B1, app_id: A2, some param: blah, another param: blahblahblah, payment method: GPAY, last param: someuniquestring

Payment request to app_name_foo for brand: B2, app_id: A3, some param: blah, another param: blahblahblah, payment method: GPAY, last param: someuniquestring

Payment request to app_name_foo for brand: B2, app_id: A1, some param: blah, another param: blahblahblah, payment method: CREDITCARD, last param: someuniquestring

Payment request to app_name_foo for brand: B2, app_id: A4, some param: blah, another param: blahblahblah, payment method: GPAY, last param: someuniquestring
```

I am trying to get a table something like below:

```
BRAND     | CREDITCARD | DIRECTDEBIT | GPAY
B1        |    1       |    0        | 1   
B2        |    1       |    0        | 2
```

What I have tried so far:

```
index = app_name_foo sourcetype = app "Payment request to app_name_foo for brand" 
| chart  count over brand by method

index = app_name_foo sourcetype = app "Payment request to app_name_foo for brand" 
| chart  count over brand by "payment method"

index = app_name_foo sourcetype = app "Payment request to app_name_foo for brand" 
| chart count(eval(method==CREDITCARD)) AS CREDITCARD count(eval(method==DIRECTDEBIT)) AS DIRECTDEBIT count(eval(method==GPAY )) AS GPAY by brand
```

Unfortunately Splunk doesn't seem to recognize *payment method* or *method*. The queries above (and few more queries which I found on internet) doesn't produce any result.

If I replace *method* or *payment method* with *app_id* then I get the some result.

What am I missing? Please help.

Comment: Basically, you're to aggregate the number of transactions per payment method for each brand. Something we often do with SQL tables, right?

Comment: @DebarghaRoy yes that's correct. I am trying to schedule a report which will consist number of transactions for each payment method for each of the brands over a period of time - let's say 7 days. 
If this data is not possible per brand, I am okay with number of transactions for each of the payment methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before fields can used they must first be extracted.  There are a number of ways to do that, one of which uses the `extract` command.

```
index = app_name_foo sourcetype = app "Payment request to myApp for brand"
| extract kvdelim=":" pairdelim=","
| rename Payment_request_to_app_name_foo_for_brand as brand
| chart  count over brand by payment_method
```

You'll notice `extract` may not grab the field names as might be expected.  Also, spaces are replaced with underscores.

Now that we have fields with which to work, let's talk about the output.
Please tell us more about how the CREDITCARD, DIRECTDEBIT, and GPAY columns are derived.  How does B1 get a CREDITCARD value of 5 from only 2 events?  Where does DIRECTDEBIT come from?  How can GPAY add up to 5 from only 3 events?

Comment: OP is trying to aggregate the number of transactions per payment method for each brand.

Comment: Thanks RichG. I have updated my question.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I think the query in my answer will do it.